# Redmine API claims missing 'hours' field and returns 422 on POST to time_entry.json

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, redmine, redmine-api

I am trying to create [time entries](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_TimeEntries) in a Redmine 3.3.0.stable installation via the REST API, using the [Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) in the client software. I am using the following code:

```
    urlSuffix='/time_entries.json'

    time_entry = {
        'hours':       0.25,
        'project_id':  1,
        'comments':    'test',
        'activity_id': 1,
    }

    params = {
        'key': session.APIKey,
    }

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
    }

    requestURL = "%s%s" % (session.redmineBaseUrl, urlSuffix)
    response = requests.post(requestURL, json=time_entry, params=params)
```

`response.status_code` is always `422`, and the response contains the following localized message:

> {"errors":["Stunden muss ausgefüllt werden"]}

which translates to

> hours must be provided

However, the field 'hours' was given correctly, as you can see. Furthermore, the log file indicates that the parameter reaches Redmine correctly:

```
Started POST "/PROJECTNAMEHERE/time_entries.json?key=APIKEYHERE" for 62.178.175.81 at 2016-11-15 00:19:47 +0100
Processing by TimelogController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"1", "spent_on"=>"2016-11-15T00:19:24.513001", "comments"=>"lkj", "activity_id"=>"1", "hours"=>0.25, "key"=>"a009fdb7d15f174b31860cfa9d56fd648737d862"}
  Current user: MichaelJaros (id=5)
  Rendered common/error_messages.api.rsb (0.2ms)
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 22ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 5.1ms)
```

I have tried with the same outcome:

- all combinations of localized decimal point (`,` instead of `.`)
- passing the hours as an integer, float or string
- switching to XML as suggested by [this similar issue found in the Redmine boards](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/28134) (this makes Redmine complain about missing and invalid project id as well)
- using the `data=` parameter instead of `json=` in the `post()` method (this makes the hours value a string like `"1.0"` instead of `1.0` in the log file)

My last resort would be trying one of the [Python Redmine libraries](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api_with_python), but I can't see what they should do different in this case.

- Am I doing anything wrong?
- What exactly do they mean by:

> time_entry (required): a hash of the time entry attributes, including: [...]

in the [time entries](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_TimeEntries) documentation? When the request is in XML format, I would expect the API to require XML data for the time_entry as well, not "a hash". But maybe that part was just written inaccurately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a `pip install python-redmine` and the following code works perfectly:

```
from redmine import Redmine
redmine = Redmine (redmineBaseUrl, version='3.3.0', key=APIKey)
[...]
redmine.time_entry.create(project_id=self.projectId, activity_id=self.activityId, hours=self.getHoursRounded(), spent_on=self.startDateTime.date(), comments=self.comment)
```

I should have done it this way before messing around with this for hours yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Wrapping the time entry with a `time_entry` tag resolved the issue for me.

From:

```
   time_entry = {
        'hours':       0.25,
        'project_id':  1,
        'comments':    'test',
        'activity_id': 1,
    }
```

To:

```
   time_entry = {
        'time_entry': {
             'hours':       0.25,
             'project_id':  1,
             'comments':    'test',
             'activity_id': 1,
        }
    }
```